# Eigen with C++98 for GCC 3.3.5

Tags: c++, gcc, eigen

I'm trying to compile Eigen 3 on GCC 3.3.5 which should support C++98, but I'm not sure about the C++03 standard.
Naturally I get a myrad of errors, even "not implemented" messages from the compiler.

The [Compiler Support](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Compiler_support) section says C++98 support, yet the EIGEN_MAX_CPP_VER macro only allows 03 as minimum value. Is there a way to get real 98 support?

I assume there is no hope but I have to ask:

- Is there any way to get Eigen compiling with GCC 3.3.5?
- May Eigen 2 be an option?

---

I'm compiling with the following macros

```
#define EIGEN_MAX_CPP_VER 03
#define EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE
#define EIGEN_NO_CPUID
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using a 12 years old compiler?

Comment: yes, i'm forced to. the real-time environment i'm working on only allows this compiler

Comment: I'd suggest using Eigen 2. If you want to use Eigen 3 and find issues that are actually caused by Eigen not being C++03 compliant (which is not very different to C++98), and not by (outdated) GCC compiler issues, you may file bug reports for those.

Comment: Eigen 2 works!
i just had to add a missing cast in function `int Eigen::ei_pow(int, int)` at `Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h:55`, otherwise it compiles.